# when I choose a value from the first compbox is the value of the remaining compbox is changed

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, combobox

I have 3 compobboxes I have created an import code from a SQL table

The problem when I choose a value from the first compbox 
 the values of other compbox is changed to be like my choice

I made a separate code for each compbox
But I find it impractical because my project has 90 compoboxes
It needs time to run

Is there a more practical solution?

this is my code...

```
Dim com As New SqlCommand("select Distinct Name1 from TB_dr", Con)
        Dim RD As SqlDataReader = com.ExecuteReader
        Dim DT As DataTable = New DataTable
        DT.Load(RD)
        ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "Name1"
        ComboBox1.DataSource = DT
        ComboBox2.DisplayMember = "Name1"
        ComboBox2.DataSource = DT
        ComboBox3.DisplayMember = "Name1"
        ComboBox3.DataSource = DT
```

Comment: Don't use same DataTable instance for different comboboxes. Instead create different instances for every combobox. You don't need to load data multiple times, but create a copy of DataTable or even better use `List` instead of "heavy" DataTable for comboboxes datasource.

Comment: `ComboBox2.DataSource = DT.DefaultView.ToTable()` etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only populate a combobox on its dropdown event.
That will make your app faster cause your client may not use them all and if he uses one combobox he would populate a small amount of data only.
And no data is populated on load.
As i look at what you are trying to do which is same data for all comboboxes, you can simply put all your comboboxes in a group, and go through your group to populate them all at once.
like for each cb in that group, cb.datasource = dt.
call the datatable once